# Run PMML from R in Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark-mllib

I have created a linear regression model in R and exported it in PMML v4.3. How would I run this in Spark? I am very new in Spark and can't see any sample codes that runs a PMML file. All I am seeing is exporting PMML codes in Spark MLLib.

I am assuming there would be a function wherein your input parameters will be the dataset and the PMML file that would serve as your training model?

Answer (score 1):

The [JPMML-Evaluator-Spark](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator-spark) library provides an Apache Spark ML transformer class `org.jpmml.evaluator.spark.PMMLTransformer` exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Is this free? What I read is that we should buy the GNU Affero General Public License (AGPL) version 3.0 under openscoring.io?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [PMML4S-Spark](https://github.com/autodeployai/pmml4s-spark) to run PMML in Spark, it's as a SparkML transformer. For example:

```
import org.pmml4s.spark.ScoreModel

val model = ScoreModel.fromFile("the/pmml/model/path")
val scoreDf = model.transform(df)
```

BTW, it's free.